# Export from WPF richTextbox to OpenXml

Tags: wpf-controls

How can I export the content of a `Flowdocument` to `OpenXml` and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of research i found that is easier to export to RTF instead of OpenXML or at least no one know how to.

here is how i have done it:

```
FlowDocument doc = richTextBox1.Document;


TextRange content = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        textRange.Save(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);

        string val = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```